# What is Vaak shudddi?

Tags: yoga

1. What is Vaak shudddi ?
2. How does one achieve it ? and
3. Why is it
   important ?

I am looking for some literature references

Comment: may be this link is use full : http://www.ishafoundation.org/blog/lifestyle/what-is-vak-shuddhi-part-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Vaak Shuddhi comes from Purity of Thought , Mind and Heart. 
Vaak is the as articulated sound and when the uchharan -spoken is clean and correct it can be considered as Pure i.e. Shuddhi.

2) To achieve this  only Discipline (Abhyasa) and Bhakti will help in development; ultimately it is Mata Vaak Devis, Shree Saraswati's Anugraha Kripa alone that takes us ahead in this and it is thus also a Kala-speaking ability, with grace and fluency etc..

3) Character lies in in thought- Words and deeds. So the first two are extremely important i.e. Manas Shuddhi + Vaak Shuddhi.

---

Ref 2 above on Shree Mata Saraswati this may be noted for Sadhana to Vaak Devi Shree Saraswati:
She is also described as:

Vagdevi                              – Goddess of Speech

Jihvagravasni                     – Dwelling at the tip of the tongue

Kavijih Vagravasini              – Dwelling on the tongue of Poets

Shabdavasini                      – She who dwells in Sound

Vagisha                              – Mistress of Speech

Mahavani                            – Of great wisdom in Speech

Smriti-Sakti                        – Power of Memory

Jnana-Sakti                        – Power of Knowledge

Buddhi Sakti Swarupini      –       Whose form is the Power of Intellect
Kalpana Sakti                     – Who is the Power of Forming ideas.

Pratibha Sakti                    – Intelligence

Veda Garbha                       – the womb-source of Vedas Knowledge.

Sarva Vidya Swarupini        – All forms of Knowledge

Sarva Sastravasini              – Dwelling in the Shastras (Books of Shastra)

Granthakarini                     – Who creates the Books.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.